# configure: error: You need 32-bits luac when using lua from contrib

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, lua, vlc

I installed ubuntu 15.10 (32 and 64) bits on VMware. I am trying to compile vlc using these steps:

> https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/

I got this error:

> checking for LUA... no configure: WARNING: No package 'lua5.2' found,
>   trying lua 5.1 instead checking for LUA... no configure: WARNING: No
>   package 'lua5.1' found, trying lua >= 5.1 instead checking for LUA...
>   yes checking for luac... luac configure: error: You need 32-bits luac
>   when using lua from contrib. vlc: configure failed

I am a newbie at this. Would someone please explain how to fix this?

Comment: You need 32-bits luac

Comment: Where is 32bit luac?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/365916

Comment: @고경은 i have stuck on same error, please share anyone have solution..

Comment: mee too, Please someone link 32bit Lua lib for arch linux. Pacman/Arc 
does not have 32 bit lua.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1:i386
```

Comment: but it will remove lua5.1 package

Comment: `sudo apt install multiarch-support` first.  you could specify lua5.2:i386 in the above command as well